# The bopf does not generated after cds view activated

Tags: cds

I have a CDS view and I would like to generate in addition a BOPF object. The CDS view looks as the following:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZPOC_CDS_ORDERS'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Order for VALEAN POC'
@ObjectModel.compositionRoot: true
@ObjectModel.modelCategory: #BUSINESS_OBJECT 
@ObjectModel.semanticKey: ['DraftId', 'DraftItem']
@ObjectModel.representativeKey: 'DraftId'
@ObjectModel.writeActivePersistence: 'ZPOC_ORDERS'
@ObjectModel.createEnabled: true
@ObjectModel.deleteEnabled: true
@ObjectModel.updateEnabled: true
@OData: {
    publish: true
}
define view ZPOCCDSORDERS as 
    select from zpoc_orders
   {
    key draft_id as DraftId,
    key draft_item as DraftItem,
        order_id as OrderId,
        sales_org as SalesOrg,
        sales_dist as SalesDist,
        sales_div as SalesDiv,
        customer_id as CustomerId,
        recipient_id as RecipientId,
        po_ref as PoRef,
    }
```

In the transaction `/n/BOBF/CONF_UI`, I was searching for new generated `Z* BOPF` object but could not find anything.

What am I doing wrong?